# Is there a way to quantify distance between formal systems?

Tags: foundations

Suppose I and my twin embark on a project. I create a mathematical system, from scratch, based on the ZFC axioms. My twin, having read the HoTT book, decides to ground his system there. Does there exist a measure to gauge how related our two systems are? How much research has been put into comparing competing formal systems, in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an entire branch of mathematics dedicated to that. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!